# SQL Server : query for DENSE_RANK() grouped by a column?

Tags: sql-server

Need help constructing a SQL statement for this scenario, over an `orders` table, that holds the `orderID, customerID, itemID` and other misc. columns.

Say the table looks like:

```
OrderID CustomerID ItemID Details
1       1234       543    abc
2       1234       643    xxx
3       1234       743    try
4       5678       743    try
5       5678       999    iuy
6       5678       643    xxx
```

What I'd like to have as an additional column is, one counter that increments each time a new `customerID` begins, and another that loops over counting the items the customer purchased. I'm using `DENSE_RANK()` and I am able to do the first counter, but how do I also handle the second?

```
SELECT 
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY CustomerID) as Counter,
    *
FROM
    Orders
ORDER BY
    CustomerID ASC
```

This gives me:

```
Counter OrderID CustomerID ItemID Details
1       1       1234       543    abc
1       2       1234       643    xxx
1       3       1234       743    try
2       4       5678       743    try
2       5       5678       999    iuy
2       6       5678       643    xxx
```

And finally, what I WANT is the `Counter2` column added somehow:

```
Counter Counter2 OrderID CustomerID ItemID Details
1       1        1       1234       543    abc
1       2        2       1234       643    xxx
1       3        3       1234       743    try
2       1        4       5678       743    try
2       2        5       5678       999    iuy
2       3        6       5678       643    xxx
```

Comment: Oh, I just figured it out:

    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID ORDER BY ItemID) as     Counter2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` to get the second counter:

```
SELECT 
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY CustomerID) as Counter,
    row_number() over(partition by customerId order by orderId) Counter2,
    *
FROM
    Orders
ORDER BY
    CustomerID ASC;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/04d12/4). The result is:

```
| COUNTER | COUNTER2 | ORDERID | CUSTOMERID | ITEMID | DETAILS |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|       1 |        1 |       1 |       1234 |    543 |     abc |
|       1 |        2 |       2 |       1234 |    643 |     xxx |
|       1 |        3 |       3 |       1234 |    743 |     try |
|       2 |        1 |       4 |       5678 |    743 |     try |
|       2 |        2 |       5 |       5678 |    999 |     iuy |
|       2 |        3 |       6 |       5678 |    643 |     xxx |
```

Comment: Correct, I just ran into this page and figured that out too: http://thehobt.blogspot.com/2009/02/rownumber-rank-and-denserank.html - thank you!!